# How can I preserve insertion order in a HashSet?

Tags: java, set

I wrote the following code,

```
public int longestConsecutive(int[] nums) {
Set<Integer> num_set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int num : nums) {
    num_set.add(num);
    System.out.println("num_set: " + num_set.toString());
}
```

then I have the test case,

```
int[] nums  = {100, 4, 200, 1, 3, 2};
```

then in the last line output, the console shows,

```
num_set: [1, 2, 3, 100, 4, 200]
```

I'm wondering why the previous order was changed after the add operation.

Comment: Use `TreeSet` which considers ordering. In `HashSet` the adding order is not considered while retrieving, `List` does that. If you are using a custom class (classes that you defined) then you have to make your class `Comparable` or `Comparator` type.

Comment: If you want your `Set` of integers to be sorted, use a `SortedSet`. Change your line `Set<Integer> num_set = new HashSet<Integer>();` to something like `SortedSet<Integer> numSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stating the [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) documentation

> It makes **no** guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will **remain** constant **over time**.

If you want to use a `Set` that remains natural order, use a [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) instead.

> A Set that further provides a total ordering on its elements. The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator typically provided at sorted set creation time.

Edit:
A `Set` does by definiton not say anything about the order of its elements. For exmaple, two Sets are equals if both contain the same elements and have the same size. The iteration order of a `Set` is dependent on the implementations and may change between versions, so you should not make any assumptions on it. It may depend on the value of `#hashCode`, but it may as well depend on the insertion order or something else in the future. However, we should not care, because if you do you should use a `List` or a `SortedSet` instead.

Comment: Why the previous order was changed after the add operation?

Comment: @Vicky Is there anything else that is unclear? Otherwise, you could mark this as answer.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you want to preserve insertion order. There's a class called `LinkedHashSet` for this. Here's some sample code for you:

```
int[] nums  = {100, 4, 200, 1, 3, 2};
Set<Integer> ints = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for(int i : nums) {
    ints.add(i);
}
System.out.println(ints);
```

The above code prints: `[100, 4, 200, 1, 3, 2]`

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) says:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set **(insertion-order)**. Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the set. (An element e is reinserted into a set s if s.add(e) is invoked when s.contains(e) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)

Answer (score 1):

Glains has already answered your question. Still I'd like to add some: there are **interfaces** in Java library which provides **contracts** to the developers, making promises that they can be used in which ways.

Just like your question, basic interface [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements.

And your `implementor` [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), which already clearly specifies the fact that **order** is not guaranteed, in which case you should **NOT** expect any order-related promises.

> It makes **no** guarantees as to the iteration **order** of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

And specifically, Java provides another interface [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) instead to ensure **order** you are asking for:

> A Set that further provides a total ordering on its elements. The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator typically provided at sorted set creation time.

So in your case, you should find an `implementor` that implements the *interface* `SortedSet`, like [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Normally we care not much about the implementation details since they can be **adjusted/changed** without our knowing, while on the other hand the **promises** the library developers made in the **official documentation** will be kept always.