# Inserting into HashMap messes with sorting

Tags: java, android, hashmap

Based on this class

```
public class Record {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "records";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_SPEED = "speed";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";

    private int id;
    private String longitude;
    private String latitude;
    private String speed;
    private String timestamp;

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_LATITUDE + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_SPEED + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (DATETIME('now','localtime'))"
            + ")";

    public Record(){
    }

    public Record(int id, String longitude, String latitude, String speed, String timestamp){
        this.id = id;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getLongitude(){
        return longitude;
    }

    public String getLatitude(){
        return latitude;
    }

    public String getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }

    public String getTimestamp(){
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude){
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude){
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setSpeed(String speed){
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp){
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

I have created my SQLite model

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "speeds";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(Record.CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Record.TABLE_NAME);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertRecord(String longitude, String latitude, String speed){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(Record.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        values.put(Record.COLUMN_LATITUDE, latitude);
        values.put(Record.COLUMN_SPEED, speed);

        System.out.println("VALUEEEEEEEES" + values);

        db.insert(Record.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public List<Record> getAllRecords(){
        List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Record.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + Record.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Record record = new Record();
                record.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Record.COLUMN_ID)));
                record.setLongitude(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Record.COLUMN_LONGITUDE)));
                record.setLatitude(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Record.COLUMN_LATITUDE)));
                record.setSpeed(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Record.COLUMN_SPEED)));
                record.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Record.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

                records.add(record);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();

        return records;
    }

    public List<Record> getLastTenRecords(){
        List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Record.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + Record.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC LIMIT 10";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Record record = new Record();
                record.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Record.COLUMN_ID)));
                record.setLongitude(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Record.COLUMN_LONGITUDE)));
                record.setLatitude(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Record.COLUMN_LATITUDE)));
                record.setSpeed(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Record.COLUMN_SPEED)));
                record.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Record.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

                records.add(record);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();

        return records;
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to show some data inside an `ExpandableListView`. In my scenario i sort the response of the sql query by the `COLUMN_TIMESTAMP` and trying to parse it in the type of `HashMap<String , List<String>` in order for the `ExpandableListView` to recognize it.

The problem is that even tho the result is sorted(and I can see it when looping and printing one by one), after I use this method to parse and put into HashMap, the sorting is gone.

```
public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getLastTenData(Context context) {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<>();

        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        List<Record> recordList = databaseHelper.getLastTenRecords();
        for(int i=0; i<recordList.size(); i++){
            List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
            myList.add("Y: "+recordList.get(i).getLatitude());
            myList.add("X: " + recordList.get(i).getLongitude());
            myList.add("Km/h: "+recordList.get(i).getSpeed());
            expandableListDetail.put(recordList.get(i).getTimestamp(), myList);
            System.out.println("check "+String.valueOf(i)+"    "+recordList.get(i).getTimestamp());
        }

        System.out.println(expandableListDetail);

        return expandableListDetail;
    }
```

What I mean is that `expandableListDetail` is not sorted by key when it should be.
Any help?

Comment: Just use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `new HashMap<>()`

Comment: @Deadpool wow that was so easy... You can't imagine how long i have been stuck on this.

Comment: You could also use a `TreeMap` which orders item based on key so e.g. putting 3 items into the map with keys c, a, b will result in a, b, c ordering when iterated over. `LinkedHashMap` on the other hand will retain the order the items are put into the map in the first place regardless of key ordering; so in the previous example it would result in c, a, b ordering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If have already ansered a similar question (regarding `HashSet`) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131969/how-can-i-preserve-insertion-order-in-a-hashset/51131993#51131993).

Similar, a `HashMap` is unordered, so adding values to it and then iterating over the map will not yield items in the order you initially added them.

Why does `LinkedHashMap` solve the issue? (picking up on the idea from @Deadpool)

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its 
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is
>   normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map
>   (insertion-order).

Why does `TreeMap` solve the issue? (picking up on the idea from @tomgeraghty3)

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys